# Is it necessary to test css styles with QUnit?

Tags: css, ember.js, ember-qunit

I'm now developing a web app with EmberJS and meanwhile I use the build-in QUnit framework to test it, I got a few questions about test and styles listed below.

1 Is it necessary to test css styles? I mean write test case instead of visually check in browser.

2 Should I use px or rem in the style sheet? I used to use rem for responsive design and HiDPI devices, but recently I found that px can do the job, and there are voices that supports px over rem. Like this https://mindtheshift.wordpress.com/2015/04/02/r-i-p-rem-viva-css-reference-pixel/

3 Something really, really wired... I set a span's font-size to be 15px, but QUnit test results turns to be 18px (html base font-size is 16px, manually set). Just very simple DOM structure, no other font-size rules attached.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BNUk.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am opposed to this form of 'testing'. It's just locking the implementation into an inflexible design - and adding more cost to change it later, as/when the over-specified brittle tests fail.

Comment: @user2864740 So just visual check in the browser? Or are there any better ways to test styles as it is getting more and more complicated? Thank you;)

Comment: What do you mean by "test styles"? Can you give an example?

Comment: @MillerHD At the end of the day the browser is 'actual' way the rendering occurs; odd quirks and all across the myriad of supported devices. There are tools enable mass-browser testing and UI QA may also be interested in capturing pixel-perfect comparison for regression cases, etc. However, this is not the point of a Unit Test or a Behavior Test. QUnit is a [unit] testing framework that allows behavioral testing through simulation of events, YMMV with such blurred line.

Comment: @MillerHD However, even in a distinct behavior test (eg. powered by Selenium or similar), one generally wouldn't "test css styles" or even how such are rendered on screen. Instead, one would test things such as applied CSS classes: ie. a certain behavior test may 'pass' if there is a modal box that appears that is marked as an 'error', regardless of how such is actually rendered/visible on the screen.

Comment: @MillerHD Of course, if there is a very specific thing that is being tested (ie. if there was a 'rounded corners backfill library') then it may make sense to test for exactly computed pixel layout .. but this is not a general case and still prone to misrepresentation.

Comment: This might be better suited for softwareengineering SE

Comment: @JohnOsborne when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)